# Problem 1.23 in Fulton's Algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In Fulton's book "Algebraic curves - an introduction to Algebraic Geometry" (freely available from the author's web page http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf )
problem 1.23 says:
Give an example of a collection $\mathscr S$ of ideals in a Noetherian ring such that no maximal member of $\mathscr S$ is a maximal ideal.

But a lemma just before this problem says:

Lemma. Let $\mathscr S$ be any non-empty collection of ideals in a Noetherian ring $R$.Then $\mathscr S$ has a maximal member, i.e. there is an ideal $I$ in $\mathscr S$ that is not contained in any other ideal of $\mathscr S$ .

Does this mean that the only solution for the exercise is ${\mathscr S}=\emptyset$? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: There's a subtle yet pretty important difference between "maximal ideal" and "maximal ideal among all ideals that..." . Not the same!

Comment: The maximal member of your collection need not be a maximal ideal. There may be some ideal outside the collection that contains it. Cheesy example: let $I$ be non maximal and let your collection consist of only this ideal.

Comment: I now see my rather obvious mistake. The word "maximal" in "maximal member of $\mathscr S$" and "maximal ideal" has two different meanings, and the second really means "maximal ideal of $R$". I took it to mean instead "maximal ideal of $\mathscr S$". But obviously the second meaning is understood  when one says "maximal ideal".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DonAntonio's answer is nice, but unless I am missing something there seems to be a nice "trivial" example as well.

Let $\mathcal S = \{ I \}$ where $I$ is not maximal.
Then the maximal element in $\mathcal S$ is $I$, but $I$ is not maximal (by definition).

Comment: Nice ! I used $\;\Bbb Z\;$ because this ring is a rather familiar example in very elementary mathematics, but your example is simpler and very nice.  +1

Answer (score 3):

For example, in $\;R:=\Bbb Z\;$ , take

$$\mathcal L:=\left\{\,I\le \Bbb Z\;|\;\forall\,x\in I\,,\,\,4\,\mid\,x\,\right\}$$

Find a (the) maximal element in $\;\mathcal L\;$ , and now show it is *not* a maximal ideal of $\;R=\Bbb Z\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

You may consider a noetherian U.F.D. of dimension $>1$, e.g. $k[X,Y]$, where $k$ is a field, and take for  $\mathscr  S$ the set of of ideals generated by the irreducible polynomials, which are prime ideals of height $1$, and therefore are not maximal since $  k[X,Y]$ has dimension $2$ and is catenary.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can just take collections of non-maximal ideals, the non-closed points from the spectrum. Take some irreducible affine curve $C$ and consider the generic point $\eta \in C$. This is basically the same example as Rubens, but in the context of curves.